# How would I be able to extract data from an API and display it in a webpage, using DJANGO?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I received a task that asks me to create a webpage and populate it with data from a given API.

The API data is in a REST JSON format. Furthermore,  I am using Django as a framework, so that I avoid any issues with cross-origin requests.

I've been looking into the request module and have got as far as:

```
import requests
import pprint
url = ''
r = requests.get(url)
pprint.pprint(r.json()['results'][1])
```

I am able to get the information printed in the terminal. However, I am confused about how I would implement this into an HTML page.

I am new to working with APIs so any help would be appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use ajax to go about working with api in the front-end. Using the Pokemon API to practice. Of course first see what you are working with by console.log for api. Once you have the data then assign it to an html element. Here's how I'd go about it using jquery.

```
<script 
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto',
    type: 'GET',
    // headers: { "X-CSRFToken" : getCookie("csrftoken") },
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log("sucess From Name choosing", serverResponse);
        // globe variables for clearing table and adding to it
        console.log(data.name);
        document.getElementById("pokemonName").innerHTML = data.name;
        }
})
</script>
<body>
<h1 id = "pokemonName">This is a Pokemon API playground</h1>
```

Ajax "GET" the api and if success then so and so happens to the api.
There are other tools you could use when using the ajax for api. Like when if fails.